# Does Service pack have all the changes in a cumulative update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, patching

I have always thought that all the changes in the CU's are rolled up into the next services pack.  I recently was looking at changes in [SQL 2016 SP2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052908/sql-server-2016-service-pack-2-release-information), and [SQL 2016 CU15 for SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4495257/cumulative-update-15-for-sql-server-2016-sp1).

I was surprised to see that none of the KB in SP1CU15 was mentioned in the SP2.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [SQLServerBuilds](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2016x) SP1 CU15 was released after SP2.

SP1 CU15 was released on 2019-05-16, SP2 was released on 2018-04-24.

Given that from SQL 2017 there will no longer be any service packs, this is no longer relevant moving forwards, but in the past Microsoft would release fixes in parallel for supported service packs. As an example [this kb article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4489150/fix-filtered-index-may-be-corrupted-when-you-rebuild-index-in-parallel) describes an issue that had a fix that was included in two separate CU's, CU15 for SP1 and CU7 for SP2.

For confirmation of the data on [SQLServerBuilds](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2016x) we can check the file details on both [SP2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56836) and [CU15 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54613)

In addition to this as pointed out by [David Browne](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/126936/david-browne-microsoft), there is a development and test overhead for all new SP's, meaning an SP does not necessarily contain all fixes in previous CU's by date - this is due to the time taken for finalising and testing the SP.

Comment: Also a SP may not have all the fixes released in the previous CU, as the SP takes a while to finalize and test.

Comment: Thanks Guys,  I have a server which is at 13.0.4224.16.  Originally I thought I will install SP2 and then latest CU(CU7) to get to the latest version.  But after this question and clarification about dates, I was wondering if I can get by, by just installing the latest SP1CU which is CU 15 and get all the fixes?  Does Microsoft release latest CU's with latest fixes to all the services packs? Probably not for ever, if not how long do I have before Microsoft stops releasing CU for a previous SP.